# Execute function after page has finished downloading and bootstrapping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onload

I've tried $evalAsync and $viewContentLoaded and all of these things seem to initiate when Angular has finished populating the template.

What I want to do is, within a directive:

1. Has Angular finished replacing the template?
2. Have all of the images and other assets (specified by the template) finished downloading?
3. If so, do this-->

I've tried a bunch of things, but I just want a definitive answer on how to do this the correct Angular way.

Answer (score 0):

See [is there a post render callback for Angular JS directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125078/is-there-a-post-render-callback-for-angular-js-directive) 
and [AngularJS - How to query the DOM when directive rendering is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235669/angularjs-how-to-query-the-dom-when-directive-rendering-is-complete)

Unfortunately, there is no way to determine when rendering is complete (e.g., there is no event for this).  Using $timeout seems to be the only workaround available.

Comment: This seems to be a workaround:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/PCDBQORa0u4/6JduMxYFnQoJ

But I can't get it to function correctly.

Comment: @dictions, are you using ng-include instead of a directive template?  If so, see if [$includeContentLoaded](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude#$includeContentLoaded) helps.  I believe that event was added to Angular sometime after that google group post.

Comment: We're using routes and ng-view. not ng-include. That's why I've tried to use $viewContentLoaded, which is I assume the ng-view equiv of $includeContentLoaded. I can't seem to get it to work though, anyone have a working jsfiddle of it? And when exactly is the event called?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454383/angularjs-targeting-elements-inside-an-ng-repeat-loop-on-document-ready and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980121/angularjs-isotope-calling-isotoperelayout-after-page-loads

Comment: Tried it, and it is almost perfect, but the event gets triggered directly BEFORE the browser replaces all of the template tags. I can deal without knowing when the ng-view resources (imgs etc) are finished downloading, but is there another event fired directly after the {{}}'s are replaced?

I know you've said there isn't. I'm just trying to cover my bases.

Comment: And for a while, I thought directives were the answer, but they get called when angular has the data ready, but not necessarily AFTER the dom has rendered. In most cases that is best, but in my case (trying to create some sort of loading screen), it isn't ideal.

Comment: It'd be great if there was somehow a "$last" for ng-view. Ng-repeat has that boolean, and that works fantastically. Is there an equiv?

Comment: How about inside the $viewContentLoaded event handler you call $timeout?  That should put the $timeout's callback function on the JavaScript event queue.  Then hopefully Angular will have rendered by the time your $timeout callback executes.

Comment: But that means that it will have a loading screen for a set amount of time ever time, not good enough, but I've found a solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for directive that looks for all nested include to be loaded in their contents:

http://www.sangwine.net/jim/index.php/2013/05/how-to-detect-when-all-your-nested-includes-have-loaded-their-content-in-angularjs/